# How to test action which dispatches multiple times?

Tags: unit-testing, redux, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme

Description: My action has multiple dispatches. While testing that action in 'Jest', it's pointing to every dispatch.

**Action Code Eg.:**

```
const export myAction = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({payload: {data1: 'Data - 1'}, type: 'UPDATE_DATA_1'});
  dispatch({payload: {data2: 'Data - 2'}, type: 'UPDATE_DATA_2'});
  dispatch({payload: {data3: 'Data - 3'}, type: 'UPDATE_DATA_3'});
}
```

**Test Code Eg.:**

```
it('myAction()', () => {
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
  const expected = {payload: {data3: 'Data - 3'}, type: 'UPDATE_DATA_3'};
  
  myAction()(mockDispatch);
  expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected);
});
```

**Issue:** As dispatch gets called 3 times, it's failing if I try to test particular one.

**Query:** How to test individual dispatch or how to test three of them at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found what I wanted

```
it('myAction()', () => {
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
  const expected = {payload: {data3: 'Data - 3'}, type: 'UPDATE_DATA_3'};
  
  myAction()(mockDispatch);
  expect(mockDispatch.mock.calls[2][0]).toEqual(expected);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A slicker way to assert the last dispatch would be to use [.toHaveBeenLastCalledWith()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeenlastcalledwitharg1-arg2-)

```
it('last dispatch is data3 payload, when myAction() is invoked', () => {
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
  
  myAction()(mockDispatch);

  expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith({
    payload: {data3: 'Data - 3'}, 
    type: 'UPDATE_DATA_3'
  });
});
```

Or if you wanted to check all 3 dispatches use [.toHaveBeenNthCalledWith()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeennthcalledwithnthcall-arg1-arg2-):

```
it('dispatch all 3 payloads, when myAction() is invoked', () => {
  const mockDispatch = jest.fn();
  
  myAction()(mockDispatch);

  expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1, {
    payload: {data1: 'Data - 1'}, 
    type: 'UPDATE_DATA_1'
  });
  expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(2, {
    payload: {data2: 'Data - 2'}, 
    type: 'UPDATE_DATA_2'
  });
  expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(3, {
    payload: {data3: 'Data - 3'}, 
    type: 'UPDATE_DATA_3'
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can I use it to test particular nth function that it has been called or not no matter passing any argument? I tested and it works, but wanted to know if that is the right way.

Comment: You could use `.toHaveBeenCalledTimes(number)` to check if the function was called a specified number of times regardless of the arguments passed. [More info](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber)

Comment: thank you but that's not the solution I guess. "toHaveBeenCalledTimes" will count every call of particular mock function, no matter where it's got called.